# How to get list of sld with a specific symbol?

Tags: python, geoserver, sld, xml

I am using geoserver and python to manipulate the things in geoserver. Geoserver have the ability for the REST API. Now i am trying to get the list of sld with a specific symbollizer. for example i want to get all sld's with a line symbollizer used in it. 
Is there any way how to do it.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  For questions that involve code we ask that you show us where you are stuck with your own code by including a [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) in your question.  There is an [edit] button beneath your question which will enable you to do that and a **`{}`** button that enables you to format any highlighted code nicely.

Answer (score 1):

There is no easy way to do this. About the only thing I can think of is to either fetch all of the SLD via REST (or cd to the styles folder) and then use grep to find lines that contain `LineSymbolizer` and hope it isn't in a comment!

Comment: ok so i have to loop through every sld and collect the symbolizers? @iant

Comment: I think so I'm afraid

Comment: Or you can write your own server side code that does the loop without transferring all the styles to the client. Could be interesting to extend GeoServer own REST interface to allow xpath based queries for example (not trivial, but would be good)

Comment: I have read the REST API and i did not found any thing about this. I think the only way is to iterate through every sld after parsing the xml and then checking the Line,point,polygon or the text symbolizer nodes. @AndreaAime

Comment: Yes, mines were suggestions for improving the code, not something that we already have.